# Martial arts fighting style for my spellswords?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, melee

There is a kingdom in my world. Scholars of said kingdom discover  Skycite: a crystal-like metal. 
Swords made with this material are indestructible and, with some training in magic, users can levitate the swords - using them with **a range of 2 meters** in any direction. Levitating swords can be taken from his user by an enemy with stronger magical skills. It is nearly impossible to take the sword by normal means. Only the best spellswords can use more than 2 swords. Skycite is an expensive material.

Considering that the kingdom that discovered this material is a race of humanoid cats with an extra tail with prehensile grip, **how different can be melee combat for my race with 3 extra swords?** (3 extra = besides one in each hand, one in the tail, and two levitating swords)

**PS: Weight matters and any item made with Skycite can levitate with magic. Magic is similar to chakra. Stronger bodies help with the stamina drain**

Comment: Too Broad. There are unlimited differences because you're allowed to levitate the swords within 2 meters. That means you don't have to hold or grip the swords - a cat with enough mind power (or however they have magic) can levitate an essentially an unlimited amount of swords, allowing an unlimited amount of combinations and differences.

Comment: I think Alex was trying to limit this to two levitating swords, @Aify. See my suggested edit, which might help to clarify that point.

Comment: You need to add a lot more details before this question can be answered. What does it take to lift the swords? Does weight matter? (ie could they make a sheild out of it and lift it just the same as a sword) Does it drain a person more to have three swords than two? What gives one user power over his sword and no let the enemy just take it off him? If someone gets knocked back does their sword move with them or would it drop to the floor as it moved out of range? Can they fight with as much force behind these swords? And many, many more aspects of this design.

Comment: Too broad. Though the simple answer is very diiferent.

Comment: Allow me to once again ask you to use proper punctuation. Sentences are divided from each other by a period and a space in English. You should do that in your writing.

Comment: Voting to close as _too-broad_. According to the [Black Belt Wiki](http://www.blackbeltwiki.com/martial-arts-styles), there are over a 150 different fighting styles. There's simply no means by which to judge one answer to this question as better or more correct than another.

Comment: Agreed, it's too broad.  You'd be surprised at how much variation there can be.  The key question I would have is what can you do to deflect a spellsword.  If you block my spellsword with yours, I'm just going to let it pivot around your sword and continue going towards your heart.  Blocking is very dependent on the physics of exactly what forces you can apply to the sword.

Comment: Hey there, just a little reminder: we have a [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on the Meta-Site where you can test a question to get feedback on the style and the scope if you want to test a question before releasing it onto the Main-Site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four swords does not really make sense. Assuming that your cats share some human limitations, and there is no way to answer this otherwise, so I feel safe in this assumption, they can really only focus on one thing at a time. In combat being able to focus on what you are doing is nice, so we can assume the cats will only do one thing at a time.

This means that having four copies of the same weapon is waste. What you want is to have options and alternatives. This will allow the cat to have responses to whatever the enemy does and have alternatives that the enemy finds difficult to respond to. This style would be fluid and flexible with the cat changing stances and weapons on the fly. And the poor enemy being constantly off balance. I am guessing the focus would be to gain and maintain momentum.

Neither the tail nor the skycite seem like they could give lots of leverage so the primary attack and defense should come from the hands as with humans. Either sword and shield or a two handed weapon is practical. This part works as with humans, so you should give the cats full variety of human styles as appropriate to situation.

The skycite weapon should probably be fairly small given that this is presumably a rare material. Something more like "soul dagger" than a sword. It would essentially act as a complement to the main weapon. It would be used to either create openings for attacks with main weapon, dagger to the face is pretty distracting, or for close range attacks on enemies who get inside the range of the primary weapon.

So trying to wrestle a cat with one of these daggers would probably result in dagger wounds to your neck and back. Offensively eyes and face would be the targets for easy targeting and maximum distraction.

Use of the tail would probably be things that do not particularly require leverage but benefit from wide swings. A light mace could be used to swipe the opponents legs below their defense. A chain could entangle their legs for reduced balance and mobility. A hooked weapon could do both and even cause wounds. The tail might also be used for throwing darts.

In any case tail attacks would be low quality extra attacks done while focusing on other weapons. Cats would train to do tail attacks without distracting themselves or giving the opponent advance warning that they should worry about their legs.

In any case what I, and possibly some of the people complaining about this being overly broad, am really saying, is that there would not be one true style any more than there is for humans. Since cats have two hands they start with all the flexibility of humans and then **add on top of that**. You should show off that flexibility. Hope the bulk of my answer gives some help on that.

Comment: Honestly for a metal, indestructible is a bit lacking in description instead of a dagger I would want to make some metal wire, the thinest epee type sword, some throwing needles or an arrow head.